# Obliged to use Constraints in Prolog

Tags: prolog, constraints, clpfd

I'm currently trying to solve this puzzle [houses](https://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/puzzle/house/) using only constraints provided by the clpfd prolog library, which means I cannot use backtracking!

Basically I want to find out which pairs of houses should be made in order to only have 2 distances between all the connections.

My input is a list of coordinates like this `[[0,0],[0,3],[2,0],[3,0],[2,1],[3,1],[2,2],[3,3]]` And a solution for it would be:

```
[
   [[0,0],[0,3]],
   [[2,0],[3,1]],
   [[2,1],[3,0]],
   [[2,2],[3,3]]
]
```

My current progress is this one:

```
connect(Houses):-
    %There are only 2 distances and they're different
    length(Distances, 2),
    all_distinct(Distances),

    %One connection per 2 houses (pairs) means half the number of houses as connections
    length(Houses, NHouses),
    NConnections #= NHouses // 2,
    length(Connections, NConnections),

    restrictDistances(Connections, Distances), %restrict every connection to have one of the two distances


    %All the houses must be connected
    append(Connections, ConnectedHouses),
    ensureAllConnected(Houses, ConnectedHouses), %table

    removeSymmetries(Connections), %avoid symmetries

    %flatten list and labeling
    append(ConnectedHouses, HousesCoordinates),
    labeling([], HousesCoordinates),
    write(Connections).

/*
    All distances of all connections are one of the two distances
    Distance is kept squared to keep it an integer i.e. dist(connection) = dist([[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]) = (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2
*/
restrictDistances([], _).
restrictDistances([[[X1, Y1], [X2, Y2]]|Connections], Distances):-
    DiffX #= X2 - X1,
    DiffY #= Y2 - Y1,
    Dis #= DiffX * DiffX + DiffY * DiffY,
    % element(Idx, Distances, Dis), %element
    member(Dis, Distances), %element
    restrictDistances(Connections, Distances).

/*
    Ensures all houses are connected
*/
ensureAllConnected([], _).
ensureAllConnected([H|Houses], ConnectedHouses):-
    member(H, ConnectedHouses),
    % element(_, ConnectedHouses, H),
    ensureAllConnected(Houses, ConnectedHouses).

/*
    Remove symmetries and connection permutations in final result
*/
removeSymmetries([_]).
removeSymmetries([[[X1, _], [X2, _]], [[X3, Y3], [X4, Y4]]|Connections]):-
    X1 #=< X2,
    X1 #=< X3,
    X3 #=< X4,
    removeSymmetries([[[X3, Y3], [X4, Y4]]|Connections]).
```

The worst part is that **this code works**, however the predicate `member` cannot be used because it uses backtracking... And yes, the predicate `element` exists, but I am unable to replace with it because if I replace first one the output is different, and if I replace the second one I get an instantiation error.

Comment: You could try `memberchk/2`, which does not produce multiple solutions.

Comment: How would I implement it? @DanielLyons I'm not familiar with that predicate, but just replacing it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the problem is underspecified, because there are more than one kind of distance, e.g. Euclidean distance and Hamiltonian distance. Apparently, Euclidean distances are intended, otherwise you get multiple solutions for this instance.

For this puzzle, it is useful to think about what subtasks might be encoded with global constraints. Here are some hints:

- You need to find a matching - that can be encoded with
  `assignment(Xs,Xs)`.
- You can use `table/2` to encode the *(house,house,distance)* relation.
- You can use `nvalue/2` to constrain
  the number of distinct distances.

These are global constraints in SICStus Prolog.

Comment: I actually ended up using this without reading your answer! I converted the list of houses to a list of IDs that could be used with constraints, so it ended up fully working, Thanks anyway!